# How to select minimum and maximum time per for each day and userid using mysql query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have mysql 5.7.40 db table with simple layout as

```
| userid | datetime         | ipaddress |
|--------|------------------|-----------|
| 1      | 25-11-2022 05:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 1      | 21-11-2022 05:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 2      | 22-11-2022 11:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 1      | 23-11-2022 22:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 2      | 25-11-2022 14:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 3      | 20-11-2022 18:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 3      | 23-11-2022 05:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 2      | 11-11-2022 09:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 1      | 22-11-2022 11:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 2      | 23-11-2022 13:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 2      | 08-11-2022 12:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 1      | 04-03-2022 11:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 3      | 25-11-2022 10:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
| 3      | 23-11-2022 15:30 | 10.15.1.1 |
```

I want to have the output per each userid and each day in one record, showing start time and start ipaddress and end time and end ipaddress, using mysql query.

```
| userid | date       | start ipaddress | start time | end ipaddress | end time |
|--------|------------|-----------------|------------|---------------|----------|
| 1      | 25-11-2022 | 10.15.1.1       | 05:30      | 10.15.1.1     | 14:30    |
| 1      | 26-11-2022 | 10.15.1.2       | 06:20      | 10.15.1.2     | 16:30    |
| 2      | 22-11-2022 | 10.15.1.4       | 10:21      | 10.15.1.3     | 12:30    |
| 3      | 23-11-2022 | 10.15.1.6       | 12:30      | 10.15.1.5     | 16:30    |
| 2      | 25-11-2022 | 10.15.1.3       | 07:45      | 10.15.1.3     | 15:30    |
| 3      | 21-11-2022 | 10.15.1.1       | 04:33      | 10.15.1.1     | 19:30    |
```

I've tried to use self join and inner join with no success, hope someone can help with a straight forward solution.
Also I am concerned about the query timing, since this table has millions of records.

*Please note that the data used in sample above is not consistent, just to deliver the idea of what I want to achieve.*

Your help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: There's also some issue with the ip addresses from the input table to the expected output.

Comment: You should avoid storing dates with the varchar datatype too. MySQL allows you to use the DATETIME format and gives you plenty of tools for manipulation of that datatype.

Comment: @lemon Well noted. I already mentioned that the data used sample is not consistent and just made to deliver the idea of what I was after, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `datetime` is actually a datetime column something like this should work:

```
SELECT v.userid,
    v._date,
    ul1.ipaddress AS start_ip,
    TIME_FORMAT(v._start, '%H %i') AS start_time,
    ul2.ipaddress AS end_ip,
    TIME_FORMAT(v._end, '%H %i') AS end_time
FROM (
    SELECT userid, min(datetime) AS _start, max(datetime) AS _end, DATE(datetime) AS _date
    FROM userlogin
    GROUP BY userid, DATE(datetime)
) v
    JOIN userlogin ul1 ON ul1.datetime = v._start AND ul1.userid = v.userid
    JOIN userlogin ul2 ON ul2.datetime = v._end AND ul2.userid = v.userid
```

The idea is to join the table to a view of itself which is already grouped by date and with the start and end times. You can read more here about various approaches: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Unfortunately it appears you might be storing `datetime` as varchar as mentioned in the comments which makes this a bit trickier. You can probably implement the above approach with a bit of data manipulation though using `str_to_date()`.

*It's always best to include schema and sample data in your question.* A [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) or the like would be even better.

Comment: Cannot thank you enough, @Eaten by a Grue. Actually the real table had about 40 columns and nearly a million record, and your approach was quite decent to help me do the exact needed function, at least with what mysql 5.7.40 had to offer.